# Can we use restTemplate in service classes instead of controller classes in spring boot? Please provide an example if possible

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, resttemplate

Do we need to include any notations if we use restTemplate inside service classes?

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you? Just declare it as a dependency:

```java
@Service
public class WhateverService {
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    (...)
}
```

Or using constructor injection:

```java
@Service
public class WhateverService {
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public WhateverService(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
       this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    (...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either @Autowired the RestTemplate class or you can create a bean of it.